# R: How do we plot only time against some data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a data that changes every minute and want to plot the data using ggplot2, I have the date and time format as date/month/year hour:minute in a single column in csv and want to plot the data by using only hh:mm in the Xaxis.
Can someone let me know how to do that?
thanks!

Comment: Could you share your code with us?

Comment: you can read about making time series in R ex. http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html

Comment: can you pls `?dput` some of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write a proper answer without example data, so I give a general recipe for now. Easiest I think would be to read in the data with readr::read_csv() to make sure the character strings remain as such, and then use the function dmy_hm() from package lubridate to convert the character dates into POSIXct and go on from there with other functions from package lubridate. You do not need to create a time series, a data frame should work as ggplot2 can handle dates and times, and if all your dates fall within a single day, hh:mm for tick marks will be automatically used. You can also use a time scale in ggplot2 to alter the breaks and format the tick labels in the way you want. I will edit the answer, or you can edit it yourself, including actual code when example data becomes available. If you cannot share the actual data, provide fake data with the same format.